# Local notifications crashes app

Tags: ios, cordova, uilocalnotification

I'm using latest version of de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification on PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows) cli-5.2.0 (3.9.1 / 4.1.1 / 3.8.1).

Whenever my app executes the local notification code it will crash the app (only tried on iOS).

I have the following lines of code in the "deviceready" handler:

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
id: 1,
text: "Single Notification",
title: "Yo"
});
```

Any ideas of what is wrong and how I fix it?

Config xml contains:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
```

Comment: What's the error/exception?

Comment: That's quite interesting, in fact no exception or error is generated. From what I can debug, I see that the schedule function is called but shortly after the app crashes. If I remove the said code line, the app is running fine with no errors or exceptions.

Comment: Whoever down voted this needs to give a reason.

Comment: Are you able to test on android? Are you on IOS 9?

Comment: iOS 9.0.2 on iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with IOS 9.

Try:

> Add the following to your config.xml to use version 0.8.2 of this
>   plugin (recommended)::

```
<gap:plugin
 name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification-ios9-fix"
 version="0.8.2" />
```

More info https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/694 and https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/4859

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the issue.